# Number of ways to arrange 7 distinct objects in 10 distinct spots with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There are 7 distinct objects and 10 distinct spots numbered 1-10. Two of spots 7, 8, and 9 must be open. How many ways are there to arrange these objects?

I was helping a friend with this problem and was struggling to understand why our solutions differ numerically. Here are our approaches.

## Solution 1:

There are ${3 \choose 2}$ = 3 ways to select the blocked spots, leaving 8 spots open.
There are ${8 \choose 7}$ = 8 ways to select available spots. Multiply by 7! for the total = 24 * 7! = **120,960**

## Solution 2:

Consider the total number of possibilities - all 3 filled - only 2 filled.

Total: ${10 \choose 7}*7!$ = $\frac{10!}{3!}$
Choose the 7 spots and order the objects.

3 filled: $7 * 6* 5 * {7 \choose 4} * 4! = 7 * 6 * 5 * \frac{7!}{3!}$
Fill the 3 spots (7 choices for spot 1, 6 for 2, 5 for 3), leaving 7 spots available. Choose 4 from these 7 and order the remaining objects.

Only 2 filled: ${3 \choose 2}*7*6*{7 \choose 5}*5! = 3 * 7 * 6 * \frac{7!}{2!}$
Choose the 2 spots to fill, and then fill them with the objects (7 choices for spot 1, 6 for 2). Finally, choose the 5 remaining spots from the 7 available and order the objects. There are only 7 available since we assume the third spot must be open.

Result: $\frac{10!}{3!} - (7 * 6 * 5 * \frac{7!}{3!}) - (3 * 7 * 6 * \frac{7!}{2!})$ = **110,880**

I believe Solution 1 is right, but I'm not sure what specifically is wrong with Solution 2. Shouldn't they produce the same number? If not, is Solution 1 wrong?

Comment: Your first solution is wrong as it has duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it -

First, we choose spots such that exactly two spots out of number $7, 8$ and $9$ are free and one of them has an object. That can be done in

$\displaystyle {3 \cdot {7 \choose 6}} = 21$ ways.

Then we choose spots such that all three spots $7, 8, 9$ are free. There is only *one* way to do that.

Now we permute objects in $7$ spots.

So total number of arrangements $\displaystyle = 7! \cdot 22 = 110880$

As your first solution triple counts arrangements where $7, 8, 9$ are empty, it can be fixed by subtracting $2 \cdot 7!$.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your intuition the first solution is wrong. You count 3 times any combination with no object present in positions 7,8,9.

Comment: If you correct for the double counting you will obtain the correct result: $$120960-2×7!=110880.$$